# Does the dirichlet inverse of a series with finite abscissa of convergence also has a finite abscissa of convergence?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

I would like to know if  the Dirichlet inverse $L(s,g)$ of  a series $L(s,f)$
($f(1)\neq 0$) with finite abscissa of convergence also has a finite abscissa of convergence? Is there a specific criteria to ensure it is the case?

Answer (score 1):

No.

For instance, suppose $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = -1$, while $f(n) = 0$ for all $n \geq 3$. Then $F(s) = \sum f(n) n^{-s} = 1 - 2^{-s}$, which is absolutely convergent everywhere.

But it's Dirichlet inverse is $G(s) = \frac{1}{1 - 2^{-s}}$, which only converges for $\Re s > 0$.

Comment: your example does not work, because we want f(n) to have a finite abscissa of convergence.

Comment: @usere5225321 Then think of $G(s)$ as the original and $F(s)$ as the inverse.